# Discord.py | Command That Randomly Gives Role

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that rarely gives a role (with a cooldown). However, when I try to run my code, it does not work, can anyone help to improve my code?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

...

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error,commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        msg = 'wait for a while {:.2f}s'.format(error.retry_after)
        await ctx.send(msg)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.has_role("Mod")
async def addrole(ctx):
    if random.randint(1, 10000) < 2:
        member = ctx.message.author
        role = get(member.server.roles, name="Mod")
        await bot.add_roles(member, role)

    else:
        await bot.channel.send("you did not get mod")

bot.run(TOKEN HERE)
```

I am trying to make it a 0.01% chance of them getting the role. Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error? Is it likely the fact that you think it didn't work is because you didn't get the chance?

Comment: When running the bot, there was no error, but the bot didn't do the function, nothing appeared on the python console.

Answer (score 0):

`bot.add_roles` is invalid syntax, commands.Bot object does not have a `add_roles` method. Instead, you gotta use `member.add_roles(role)` instead. Same with `bot.channel`, it's supposed to be `ctx.send`.

Comment: another thing, `bot.channel`?, its supposed to be ctx.channel.send/ctx.send

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the role id instead of the role name. That way, if the name of the role changes, your code still functions. I've added comments below in my answer for you.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.has_role("Mod")
async def addrole(ctx):
    if random.randint(1, 10000) < 2:
        member = ctx.message.author
        role = ctx.guild.get_role(#the role id as an int) ###get the mod role from the server using the role id#
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send("WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER!") ###you're using ctx so passing the context is sufficient here

    else:
        await ctx.send("you did not get mod") ##you're using ctx so passing the context is sufficient here
```